# MaxMSP digital filter, understanding unroll and relation functions

Tags: c, filter, sdk, filtering, max-msp-jitter

I am very new to programming MaxMSP externals.
To practice, I am making a Moog VCF-like filter. I have based my external on the SDK lores~ example.
My external works well, but, I really want to understand all functionalities that I've implemented.
I don't understand well the relationships between **SMOOTHING_VERSION**, **lores_perform_unroll_smooth64**, and **maxvectorsize**.
Can someone explain this to me?

```
void lores_dsp64(t_lores *x, t_object *dsp64, short *count, double samplerate, long maxvectorsize, long flags){
    x->l_2pidsr = (2.0 * PI) / samplerate;
    lores_calc(x);
    x->l_a1p = x->l_a1;  // store prev coefs
    x->l_a2p = x->l_a2;
    x->l_fcon = count[1];   // signal connected to the frequency inlet?
    x->l_rcon = count[2];   // signal connected to the resonance inlet?
    lores_clear(x);

    if (maxvectorsize >= 4) {
#if SMOOTHING_VERSION
        dsp_add64(dsp64, (t_object *)x,(t_perfroutine64)lores_perform_unroll_smooth64, 0, NULL);
#else
        dsp_add64(dsp64, (t_object *)x, (t_perfroutine64)lores_perform_unroll64, 0, NULL);
#endif
    }
    else
        dsp_add64(dsp64, (t_object *)x, (t_perfroutine64)lores_perform64, 0, NULL);
}
```

Basically, why do we need an unroll function?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this was answered on the crosspost at the Cycling '74 forum: [https://cycling74.com/forums/lores~-code-understanding-unroll-and-related-functions](https://cycling74.com/forums/lores%7E-code-understanding-unroll-and-related-functions)

Comment: I asked the same question on their forum because no one answered here.